# Change DataTable Search Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Been trying to change the Search: to Filter: in my datatable that I created.

I tried this that i found:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#datatable-example_filter').dataTable({
  "aaSorting": [[ 10, "desc" ]],
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 250, 500, -1], [25, 50, 100, 250, 500, "All"]],
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "oLanguage": {
    "sSearch": "Filter: "
  }
});
} );
```

but it is not working, #datatable-example_filter is the name of the id, inside the div that is generated by dataTable

Comment: See [this](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3900/changing-search-label-in-tab0le-header) if it can help you

Comment: @TheGuest, it is exactly what he is doing, and it should work -> POC -> (OP's code) http://jsfiddle.net/c846e6mo/ Guess it is cache ...1.10.x too -> http://jsfiddle.net/5cvj0t18/

Comment: @TheGuest & david, thanks, i was targeting it erroneously. not sure how to up voate, as i think it's just a comment?

Comment: Dude, the same thing is working for me.

Answer (score 80):

The other answer that uses "oLanguage" is using legacy DataTables api.  According to DataTables v 1.10+ [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.search), the syntax is:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "search": "Filter records:"
  }
} );
```

Comment: You can also use the key `"searchPlaceholder"` alongside `"search"` to place some placeholder text in the search input.

Comment: is it possible to shift the placement of the `search` label? Shift to the right side of the `search input field` for example.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add some space between the default label and search box, so I used this method to change it to "Search:&nbsp&nbsp" and it worked!

Answer (score 18):

very easy, just put this parameter when you call data table function:

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sSearch": "<span>YOUR SEARCH TITLE HERE:</span> _INPUT_" //search
}
```

Comment: Cool! For other using angular-datatables, replace keywords with 'language' and 'search' respectively.

Answer (score 9):

Inside the Datatable Javascript `(table = $dataTable.DataTable)` add the following code:

```
language: {
  'search' : '' /*Empty to remove the label*/
}
```

I left the search empty because I wanted the info to be in the Placeholder

Ps: If you want to add a placeholder put the following code outside the Datatable initialization

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Zoeken...");
```

Answer (score 5):

I have found this code will change the Search Label ( in my case to "Filter results:" before the DataTable get populated with data.

```
var dataTable_leSrch = $('#dataTable_leSrch').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Filter results:"
    }
});
```

but when I later populate the DataTable with data the label reverted back to "Search:", so I had to add this code to my DataTable configuration to keep the label changed:

```
function fillDataTable(res) {
if ($('#dataTable_leSrch').length !== 0) {
    $('#dataTable_leSrch').DataTable({
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            headerOffset: $('#header').height()
        },
        oLanguage: {
            "sSearch": "Filter results:"
        },
        responsive: false,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: 400,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        select: true,
        destroy: true,
        aaData: res.data.Results,
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Input text box will be appended at the end automatically
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter records:"
    }
  } );
} );


// Specify where the filter should appear
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Apply filter _INPUT_ to table"
    }
  } );
} );
```

for more detail check this link  http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n

Answer (score 1):

try this **for change label** search panel

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
 "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "type somthing.. ",
            },

});
```